# Where to store files (pictures & vids) for my website?

Tags: laravel

I'm a newbie web developer and I have a basic question regarding my Laravel based website: Where should I put my files? I know there are services like Amazon S3, but firstly I don't know how to work with them, and second they are NOT FREE.

There is going to be a fairly large amount of data including pics and videos (around 10 GB).where should I store them? And how should I use Laravel to allow users to upload files?

Comment: Insofar as this is a request for recommended services, see #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

If it will be a bigger project, you should use a cloud service. This is going to be the future of backend development as it is making your project much easier and faster to mantain and run. If you want to make your own backend, this will take a long time to get it done, since you have to learn a lot of new things and should be good at it. There would be many key aspects you have to be aware of. Like securitiy, scaling, performance and so on ...   
Like you suggested **`Amazon AWS`** or imo much better **`Google Firebase`**. I think [Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs) should be your pick because it is really easy do understand and has a great documentation. Next to the storing service (Google Cloud Storage) there are many several services you could use in the future like analytics, machine learning or nosql databases. And the good thing is that you can connect them all together. 

With Google Firebase you have a [Free Spark Plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) which is completely free with some limitations. And if you scale to many users you can upgrade to the other plans, which is not very expensive. Don't forget that your own Back-End would cost you time and also money for the electricity and hardware cost.

If you have more questions be free to ask me :)